# seting the initial pose in navigation not using "2D Pose Estimate" tool in rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, pose, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I am using the navigation pkg for Kuka youbot. My question is whether there is another way to set initial and goal poses of robot in the map except using 2D Pose Estimate" tool in rviz?

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239537/seting-the-initial-pose-in-navigation-not-using-%222d-pose-estimate%22-tool-in-rviz/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All that rviz does is publish a message, which you can do from anywhere. [initialpose (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Subscribed_Topics)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0